# matching a pdf with the formula for normal distribution

Tags: functions, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

The formula for pdf of normal distribution is

$$ f(x)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{\frac{-(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$

and I have a pdf that is: 
$$ke^{-x^2-7x}$$

But I face a paradox in calculating $\mu$

From the formula:

$ {2\sigma^2} = 1 $  ______So_____  ${-x^2-7x} = {-(x-\mu)^2}$
and this gives $\mu = 0$ and then there won't be any -7x

can somebody declare it for me?

Comment: The main trick is to *complete the square* in the exponent.

Comment: @MinusOne-Twelfth Indeed, but the comment *after* the two answers stating exactly that loses a bit of impact :)

Comment: I mainly put it there in case someone reading wants a "quick highlight".

Comment: @MinusOne I did it, but I couldn't continue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ke^{-x^{2}-7x}=ke^{49/4} e^{-(x+\frac 7 2)^{2}}$. So $\mu =-\frac 7 2,\sigma=1/{\sqrt 2}$ and, for the given function to be a pdf, $k$ must be such that $ke^{49/4}=\frac 1 {\sqrt {\pi }}$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Completing the square yields
$$
-(x^2+7x) = -\left(x+\frac{7}{2}\right)^2+\frac{49}{4}
$$
so $\mu$ can only be $\mu = -7/2$. With that in hand,
$$
k e^{-(x^2+7x)} = k e^{-\left(x+\frac{7}{2}\right)^2+\frac{49}{4}}
= (ke^{\frac{49}{4}}) e^{-\left(x+\frac{7}{2}\right)^2}
= k' e^{-\left(x+\frac{7}{2}\right)^2}
$$
where $k' = ke^{\frac{49}{4}}$. Can you finish from there?

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: @Fatemehhh You're welcome.